Set Yocto root password in recipe
How do you set the root password in a bitbake recipe in yocto? I tried the following but logging into root requires no password still. I'm using mickledore
inherit extrausers

EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "usermod -p liApcZvYV/3jA root;"

Note liApcZvYV/3jA is generated via openssl passwd

This question is similar to: How to add an user and re set the root user in yocto?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Are you sure you removed the debug-tweaks image feature ? It disables the root password.

1. Check the EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES variable in your local.conf and if it has the value "debug-tweaks", remove it.
2. In your image's recipe file, for example: my-core-image.bb, do:
inherit extrausers

# printf "%q" $(mkpasswd -m sha256crypt toor)
PASSWD_ROOT="\$5\$rYe57H4Vb8RfUNdR\$m0TDKpcm0SbZRsQboez.7qI22UNIY7iBWEG4ZtAXw30"

EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "\
usermod -p '${PASSWD_ROOT}' root; \
"

3. Generate the hash with printf "%q" $(mkpasswd -m sha256crypt <your password here>)
4. Reference: https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/classes.html#extrausers
